# how to run android app only on phone ,not on tab

Tags: android

I have developed one android app which intended to run only on phone.But it also run on Tab
I have made changes in Manifest file as following-

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

But it doesn't work.
What is the way to setup android app using code which only run on phone, not on android tab.

Comment: What is not working? Do you install it through APK? Market? or through eclipse? That maybe makes a different because the store will filter it out depending on you're manifest. 

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: yes,i install through eclipse

Comment: That will be the problem see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Its says:
By declaring which screen sizes your application supports, you can ensure that only devices with the screens you support can download your application. Declaring support for different screen sizes can also affect how the system draws your application on larger screens—specifically, whether your application runs in screen compatibility mode.
To declare the screen sizes your application supports, you should include the <supports-screens> element in your manifest file.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in the Manifest.xml :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
```

If the device has no dialer and a data network, this one will be excluded from **GooglePlayStore**.

Check this: [Google Play Filtering](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)

On the other hand, if you change the **supports-screens** property you will have problems with devices with high density displays.

Good luck!